# What kind of mouse event does Angular2 support?

Tags: angular

I have used click event in Angular2, and I am curious about what other mouse events it has, for example, mouseover? In addition, where can I find all the mouse event that Angular2 support? The official documentation seems unclear regarding event.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Angular2 supports all events the browser fires https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events. If [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) is loaded additional gesture events are fired (like `tap`). Other libraries and custom elements might fire even other events.

Comment: I' m quite sure, it's not true. Angular 2 does not support none of drag&drop events.

Comment: @bartosz.baczek not sure what you mean. Sorry, seems I missed your comment previously. Angular2 supports every event fired by the DOM or by Angular2 component outputs. You can also fire any [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) and subscribe to it using `(my-event)="doSomething($event)"`

Comment: Your are right, I was wrong ;) Already forgot about this thread ;)

Comment: Glad to hear misunderstandings are gone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find some events here:

http://www.angulartypescript.com/angular-2-events/

example of mouseover in angular2

```
<div on-mouseover='over()' style="height:100px; width:100px; background:#e2e2e2">hello mouseover</div>

over(){
    console.log("Mouseover called");
  }
```